# Como evitar la inserción de registros duplicados a la BD

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

Estoy usando un `Intent Service` para ingresar los datos a la base de datos en segundo plano, no estoy muy segura si está bien lo que hice, lo que buscaba era realizar la inserción de datos sin entorpecer la interfaz.

Hasta ahora esto funciona bien, pero necesito que la inserción se realice sólo en el caso de que el registro no exista en la BD por lo que me imagino que sería necesario validar previamente los datos que ya están guardados, esto con la finalidad de evitar trabajo extra insertando una y otra vez los mismos registros

Necesito hacerlo por parte de Android Studio ya que los registros duplicados ya están solucionados en el php de la inserción. No se, si Android tiene la capacidad de guardar una especie de bandera o filtro que le diga lo que ya ha sido ingresado.

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.neni.cuidador.Cargar;
import com.example.neni.cuidador.HttpHandler;
import com.example.neni.cuidador.R;
import com.example.neni.cuidador.redes.Item_twitter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import static com.example.neni.cuidador.MainActivity.sharedPref;
import static 
com.example.neni.cuidador.redes.ActivityThree.DatoNombreTwitter;

public class ProgressIntentService extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = 
ProgressIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
String NombreTwitter;
String twitter_user, twitter_token, twitter_secret;
String tipo_publicacion;

public ProgressIntentService() {
    super("ProgressIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    NombreTwitter= intent.getStringExtra("twitter_detalle2");
    twitter_user = sharedPref.getString((getString(R.string.twt_user)), "");
    twitter_token = sharedPref.getString((getString(R.string.twt_token)),"");
    twitter_secret = sharedPref.getString((getString(R.string.twt_secret)),"");
    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Constants.ACTION_RUN_ISERVICE.equals(action)) {
            handleActionRun();
        }
    }


}

/**
 * Maneja la acción de ejecución del servicio
 */
private void handleActionRun() {



    String url2 = "http://10.0.2.2/xampp/BdApp/twitter/mentions_timeline.php?username=" + twitter_user + "&accesstoken=" + twitter_token + "&accesstokensecret=" + twitter_secret;

    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url2);
    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);


    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {

                JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject user = c.getJSONObject("user");
                    String screen_name_mencion = user.getString("screen_name");



                    if (screen_name_mencion.equals(NombreTwitter)) {
                        id_ultimo = c.getString("id_str");
                        String created_at = c.getString("created_at");
                        String fechaArray[] = created_at.split(" ");
                        String mes = fechaArray[1];
                        String dia = fechaArray[2];
                        String hora = fechaArray[3];
                        String año = fechaArray[5];

                        if (mes.equals("Jan")) {
                            mes = "01";
                        } else if (mes.equals("Feb")) {
                            mes = "02";

                        } else if (mes.equals("Mar")) {
                            mes = "03";

                        } else if (mes.equals("Apr")) {
                            mes = "04";

                        } else if (mes.equals("May")) {
                            mes = "05";
                        } else if (mes.equals("Jun")) {
                            mes = "06";

                        } else if (mes.equals("Jul")) {
                            mes = "07";

                        } else if (mes.equals("Aug")) {
                            mes = "08";

                        } else if (mes.equals("Sep")) {
                            mes = "09";

                        } else if (mes.equals("Oct")) {
                            mes = "10";
                        } else if (mes.equals("Nov")) {
                            mes = "11";
                        } else if (mes.equals("Dec")) {
                            mes = "12";
                        }
                        String fecha_mencion = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + año + "\u0020" + hora;


               new Cargar().execute("http://10.0.2.2/xampp/BdApp/ingresar_actividad.php?nombre_usuario_actividad=" + screen_name_mencion + "&id_nativo=" + id_nativo + "&fecha=" + fecha_mencion + "&tipo_red=" + "Twitter" + "&tipo_publicacion=" + "Menciones");


                    }



                }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Esta habiendo problemas para cargar el JSON");
    }


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio destruido...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Emisión para avisar que se terminó el servicio
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_PROGRESS_EXIT);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);

    Log.d(TAG, "Servicio destruido...");
}


}
```

Comment: Puedes indicar en que parte del codigo es que guardas los datos? No se ve en tu codigo. Y otra pregunta: guardas los datos en un SharePreference o en SQLite?

Comment: Este tipo de validaciones debes realizarla en el WS, puedes validar ahí si ya existe el valor.

Comment: @Jorgesys disculpa, me puedes explicar que es el WS?

Comment: @Einer Los Sharedpreferences los uso para almacenar unos Tokens de diferentes APIs, los datos se guardan en el handleactionrun() específicamente en la linea:   
new Cargar().execute("http://10.0.2.2/xampp/BdApp/ingresar_actividad.php?nombre_usuario_actividad=" + screen_name_mencion + "&id_nativo=" + id_nativo + "&fecha=" + fecha_mencion + "&tipo_red=" + "Twitter" + "&tipo_publicacion=" + "Menciones");

Comment: @flo perdón vi que llamabas el método makeServiceCall() pero en realidad quien realiza la operación con los datos es timeline.php este archivo recibe valores username, accesstoken y accesstokensecret los cuales inserta, en realidad aquí es donde se puede implementar la lógica para determinar si se inserta o no un registro.

Comment: Como dice Jorge al momento de insertar debes validar aquello, y el WS es la abreviación de webService,